# Pairing Sony bluetooth headphones with my PC, under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, bluetooth, headphones

I have the Sony DR-BT50 wireless  headphones.

I've been able to successfully pair them to my iPhone and play music through them, but no such luck with my PC.

I can add it to the bluetooth devices, but when the "Driver Software Installation" screen comes up, I get a red X and "No driver found".

Any ideas how to fix this?

(I have a bluetooth keyboard & mouse paired successfully, so it's not a problem with my laptop's bluetooth.)

Comment: And your PC is running? Ubuntu? Fedora? SuSe? Or maybe Windows XP? ...?

Comment: Windows 7; sorry should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

You have to uninstall all the bluetooth drivers and download and install the driver from Anycomm.

Described here:

[http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-hardware/8235-how-add-a2dp-support-windows-7-a.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627162524/http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-hardware/8235-how-add-a2dp-support-windows-7-a.html)

> Windows 7 came with no A2DP support
> and MS asked bluetooth hardware
> manufacturer to add this feature in
> driver upgrade. All bluetooth hardware
> on laptop where most of the time we
> need A2DP are made by Broadcomm
> (widcomm software), Toshiba or CSR.
> The last 2 manufacturer seem to have
> A2DP in Vista which should work in W7
> but for Broadcomm nothing around.  I
> have a Motorola S9 that I wanted to
> connect to Dell d410 laptop with no
> success. This old dell laptop comes
> with a BT 355 internal blutooth
> adapter and refused to connect to my
> headset. After looking around for a
> few time a figured out how to enable
> A2DP in Windows 7.
>
> First download this driver from
> Anycomm a German headset company:
>
> [ftp://drivers.anycom.com/beta/usb200...8500-vista.exe](ftp://drivers.anycom.com/beta/usb200-250-500-550/anycom-blue-usb-200-250-500-550-v6-2-0-8500-vista.exe)
>
> uninstall all your Bluetooth devices
> in device manger and ask to delete
> software also.
>
> Install the downloaded software
> natively (no compatibiliy mode needed)
>
> scan now for hardware changes in
> device manager...it should install all
> devices including an audio handsfree
> driver.
>
> Scan for your bluetooth audio and
> connect.
>
> Go to you audio output devices and
> select the headset as an output.
>
> Enjoy now stereo bluetooth music and
> movies!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with a Mini USB Bluetooth dongle from IOGear I picked up today. Device contains a standard Broadcom chip, and windows 7 could install drivers for it, but it would ask for drivers for every device, and wasn't able to actually use any of them.

The drivers shipped with the device included the full widcomm bluetooth package, which it seems most manufacturers provide. [Manufacturer's Drivers for Vista/Win7 32/64][1]

Downloaded the Bluetooth Driver installer from Broadcom's website, had to use google cache, website seemed to be down. [Broadcom Download](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php), and [Google Cache][3].

It's a small download, it downloads another installer to actually do the work. But now that it's installed, the native windows 7 bluetooth support for my stereo headphones (A2DP device) and cellphone (calls/audio) are working great.

Link1: www.iogear.com/support/driver/BT_VISTA_7_v6.2.1.500.zip
  Link3: webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0SrsQE0iqQwJ:www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php+http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us

Comment: Sorry, couldn't post more than one link.