# Connecting Sony Wireless BT Headphones DR-BT101 to Windows 7 32-bit Home Premium?

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, 32-bit, headphones

I'm looking for a way to connect Sony Wireless BT Headphones DR-BT101 to Windows 7 32-bit Home Premium.  The headphones are detected by Windows, but they appear with a yellow troubleshooting icon, and report that a driver is missing.  And when running Windows Update, they report that no driver has been found.

Additionally I have attempted visiting the [Sony Support site](http://esupport.sony.com/US/perl/swu-list.pl?mdl=DRBT101&LOC=3&tab=downloadTab) and there are no drivers listed there.

I looked at the drivers [listed in this question](https://superuser.com/questions/126001/pairing-sony-bluetooth-headphones-with-my-pc-under-windows-7) as the headphones there are similar and also made by Sony, but the aforementioned German company, Anycomm, appears to be out of business, and thus the link does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user in [this](http://cdnn.lightshedder.com/category/sony-dr-bt-101/) article had to install the drivers from the Broadcom [website](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php). He also notes:

> By the way, just installing the drivers from the Broadcom site does
>   not work. You need to download the little updater program and run
>   that. It will automatically download the right drivers for your system
>   and install them. Restart, and you should be good to go.

and that:

> After two weeks the headphone stopped working with Windows. I ended up
>   purchasing the BlueSoliel Bluetooth stack for $30. It works…so
>   far…great, and is definitely full A2DP stereo…the sound is much
>   improved from the Broadcom stack…or so it seems to me…and BlueSoliel
>   has lots of advanced options for other Bluetoothie stuff too.

So try the Broadcom driver and the updater.

Comment: Yup the Broadcom driver works by itself now, no need to download the update.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved on how to finally enable the dr-bt101 Bluetooth headset to Windows 7 Ultimate. But I am using an Compaq/HP laptop so I don't know if this  will be helpful to you. Anyway, just to give you information, first I uninstall the existing Bluetooth driver on device manager and your dr-bt101 device on devices and printers (if existing) then I've downloaded some files from HP:

1. Intel chipset installation utility
2. HP Integrated module with Bluetooth wireless technology Win 7

Then restart your PC then try to pair again your device to PC. Then go to Control Panel / Sound then change the default to your Bluetooth device.