# Why won't Sony Bluetooth Headphones Connect?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, audio, drivers, bluetooth

I have visited these SuperUser links:

[Auto-connect Bluetooth headphones in Windows 7 64bit](https://superuser.com/questions/160938/auto-connect-bluetooth-headphones-in-windows-7-64bit)

and

[Pairing Sony bluetooth headphones with my PC, under Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/126001/pairing-sony-bluetooth-headphones-with-my-pc-under-windows-7)

My new Sony bluetooth headphones do not show up as a device anywhere. I have applied the latest Windows updates.

I have a new Insignia bluetooth usb "receiver". I downloaded the Broadcom drivers to get it working, and that install seemed to go just fine. That is, the install did not fail; showed no errors; and the Insignia device is working fine. By working fine, that means I've checked everything I know to check, and all the screens indicate the device is working correctly.

I can hear -- in the headphones, not the external speakers -- the connect and disconnect tones, when I power on and power off the headphones.

Do I need to uninstall the broadcom drivers and get the anycom drivers? If so, where is the anycom download site, and what is the download called?

If not, what else can I try?

I have submitted a support email to Insignia.

Comment: Have you tried connecting the headset to another computer or to an iPhone? Just so you know the headset is working alright. Have you tried connecting another headset to your computer? Just so you know you computer / Bluetooth hardware / Bluetooth driver is working alright.

Comment: I've tried pairing with my not-so-smart-phone that does have Bluetooth. The pairing was successful. I don't have another wireless headset to try. I've put in a support ticket to Insignia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insignia's own forums provided the answer. I did not have the Sony Bluetooth instructions at home, and I needed to hold the power button down for seven seconds, until alternate red/blue blinking lights occurred.

The appropriate Windows Bluetooth device menus popped up; I added the headset; and all is well.

Insignia has good [forums](http://community.insigniaproducts.com/t5/Bluetooth-Headphone-FAQs/Insignia-Bluetooth-Wireless-Behind-the-Head-Headphones-Black-FAQ/m-p/10900#M9) from what I can see, and the "headphones would not pair up" FAQ was very helpful.